# Odd aircraft lights. 3 long warm white/yellow rectangle lights- solid, not blinking

Tags: aircraft-external-lights

Lights seen in busy commercial air traffic zone over Essex County MA at 7-7:15pm in a North/NW heading, approximately 320-330degrees. Unlike the other traffic,this was completely silent from the ground and seemed to be gliding at an angle, which leads me to believe it may have been a military delta wing aircraft with us only having a view of one side from our perspective(V shaped).

What I find particularly odd is that they didn’t have any Red & Green nav lights, no spotlight, no landing lights. In a crowded area that would seem unacceptable for an  Air Force training flight. I checked the air traffic and none of the commercial airliners matched the heading at the time.

So is this something any of you have seen or anything you have knowledge of? Someone suggested it might be a test flight of the new B-21 but as far as I know that’s only happening in CA at the moment. I doubt they are doing continental test flights already, but maybe?

No, I don’t think it was a UFO before anyone chimes in. Thank you for any help!

Comment: Keep in mind that quadcopter-style "drones" are now ubiquitous and may be showing any random display of lights.  The days of anyone paying much attention to reports of weird lights at night are probably pretty much over.  Even more traditional winged rc airplanes are also venturing out night with all sorts of bizarre lighting patterns.  PS if this is a report *from a cockpit* and you believe that you were too high for such things to have been a likely explanation, you might want to clarify that this is a report from an airplane not from the ground, *and also mention your altitude*.

Comment: But I've flown a radio-controlled model glider via conventional line-of-sight flying (no camera goggles etc) up to 4K AGL in daylight, and a well-lighted object of similar size obviously could be seen much further away at night.  Not to mention all the possibilities for semi-autonomous or fully-autonomous flight for such vehicles these days.

Comment: "*I don’t think it was a UFO*" - Yet you came here to ask about an *object* that was *flying* that you couldn't *identify*...  ;)